# Strange double equals behaviour (php)

Tags: php

My question is why does..

```
$validationFail = "1";
$validationFail .= "i88"; 
$validationFail .= "w19"; 
echo $validationFail;
if($validationFail==1){
    echo "hello world";
}
```

output 1i88w19hello world

I know that the if fails with ===, but why does this happen?

(code ran in http://phpfiddle.org/ )

Comment: You're comparing a string to an integer. PHP has dynamic typing that prefers integer comparisons, in particular when both operands look like integers.

Comment: so it converts the string to the first known integer?

Comment: Actually it would convert any string. Most strings would amount to zero in numeric context. Yours just happens to get cut down to a `1`.

Comment: In php, compare string will use strcmp() instead of == , === will fail because of === will only return true when two variable contain exactly same value.

Comment: Thank you both, apologies for the ignorance. But now i know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare a string with a number, it converts the string to a number, and then compares that with the other number. Converting a string to a number works by reading the string until it gets to the first non-numeric character. So the string `1i88w19` becomes `1`, and `1 == 1` is true.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, accepted in 10 mins....